# Sort NSString of NSDate in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

I have an array which has NSString converted from NSDate. I am getting the initial index of the array and sorting them. 
Dates are in format : 08AM , 01PM. When I try to do NSSortDescriptor, it always gives me 01PM and than 08AM.

```
//** Date string **//
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:startSection];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"ah"];
startSection = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date1];
NSString *strSection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", startSection];
```

The string above is added in NSArray. The NSArray is used below to sort the strings. And finally, the same array is used to get the initial letter and display their index in sectionforsectionIndexTitle. So I have AM8 and PM1 as sections and not 8AM and 1PM.

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start"
                                                                   ascending:FALSE
                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease] ;


NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDescriptor];
[[dict objectForKey:aKey] sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Comment: Why can't you just sort the dates?

Comment: @Georg: I am trying to sort dates to have correct sectionForSectionIndexTitle. so that the data is under correct section.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `sortUsingComparator:`? But this will involve changing the string from `08AM` to `AM08` and `01PM` to `PM01` before comparison so this assumes that they will be of that form.

```
NSMutableArray * theArray = [dict objectForKey:aKey]; /* To be sorted */
[theArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString * string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [(NSString *)obj1 substringFromIndex:2], [(NSString *)obj1 substringToIndex:2];
    NSString * string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [(NSString *)obj2 substringFromIndex:2], [(NSString *)obj2 substringToIndex:2];

    return [string1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:string2];
}];

/* theArray is now sorted */
```

Comment: I am using the same array to display it on as sectionforsectionindextitle and also compare the sorting of nsdate. How can I avoid that by having different arrays for both of them?

Comment: @lifemoveson It's kind of unclear what you mean by the same array. Obviously `NSDate`s are different from what you've in your array containing section titles. I would assume you will have a dictionary containing keys from this arrays i.e. section titles each of which maps to an array containing `NSDate`s. Can you explain a bit as to how you differ from this approach?

Comment: I have edited the question above and is explained in more detail now.